# foreign keys and normalization

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, database-normalization

Can a table have multiple foreign keys and each foreign key have a different parent table?
Does it violate any design or normalization rule?

Comment: Its a valid questions and the answer would be yes, that is quite normal, anyway the question would be more appropriate here https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: welcome, please read the guidelines on how to formulate a question that is understandable and adds value. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please: Ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Yes-or-no questions are not useful. These are faqs. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A table can most certainly have several foreign keys. This does not violate any normalization rule.